# Code for dynamic commenting feature

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, youtube

I have tried searching the internet but couldn't find what I needed.
I am familiar with php mysql html and css. However, I can't use javascript or php to make a dynamic feature like I have explained below:

I need commenting feature similar to youtube attached to photo or video.
every time the files are uploaded to the system.

The user should be able to enable or disable the feature. He will have access through Facebook login.

The one who comments will just need to provide his name and his comments.

If you have the solution or can offer any help please share the link or any code would be helpful also.

Comment: Check this : http://socialmouths.com/2012/02/16/add-facebook-comments-to-your-blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it now from Laravel. Learn it, it is awesome!!